# Do I need to delta fetch CloudKit changes as well as subscriptions?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cloudkit, cksubscription

I'm trying to implement CloudKit subscriptions. Previously I just fetch from a custom zone using `CKServerChangeToken` when my app starts and at key points in my app.

My setup purely uses a private database.

I'm just wondering if I still need to do this type of fetching if I move to using subscriptions? From the documentation I've seen it's not clear.

Rather than use a subscription query I'm using `CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate` and looping round all my record types to register for notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you still need to use a `CKServerChangeToken` even if you implement `CKQuerySubscription`. This is how a typical (from what I've seen) CloudKit app works to keep its data in sync:

1. **Fetch on Launch** - When the app launches or becomes active again, check your `CKServerChangeToken` and fetch any new data.
2. **Fetch from Notifications** - Update records from background (i.e. silent) push notifications as they come in from your record `CKQuerySubscription`s so that your data fresh.

Apple describes notifications as "best effort" which means sometimes they aren't going to arrive (and believe me, sometimes they don't). So I have found it useful to periodically fetch new changes (like every few minutes) just in case my app missed a change notification.

Here is some sample code of how to register for all changes to a `Task` record type:

```
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Task", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), subscriptionID: "subscriptionTask", options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion])

let info = CKNotificationInfo()
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
info.alertBody = "" //This needs to be set to improve notification priority
subscription.notificationInfo = info

let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { subscriptions, subscriptionIDs, error in
  //...
}

let container = CKContainer(identifier: "...")
container.privateCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Good question. Yes, you do register the `CKQuerySubscription` on launch. But as long as you set the `subscriptionID` (example: "subscriptionTask") it will harmlessly overwrite the same subscription on the CloudKit server and your app will continue being notified of `Task` changes.